# Share session between two rails4 applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am creating a application with devise. there is two domain name 1) www.test.com and 2) www.hello.com both domain pointing to same application. so I want to share session(current_user) between both app. user will login on (1) and it should access on domain(2).

Please suggest what's the best way todo it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic issue here is the way in which cookies work (which of course sessions depend on). A cookie has a domain attribute and browsers only send cookies whose domain match the request host (there's a little bit of subtlety of the meaning of a period at the start of the domain)

Furthermore, when setting a cookie, browsers will only accept a domain that is a parent domain of the current domain and which is not a public domain). For example if you are receiving a response from `www.example.com` it can set cookies for `www.example.com` or `example.com`, but not `.com` (Browsers have a [list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat) of which domain names shouldn't be allowed).

All this to say that if your two apps don't share a common parent (as it is in your case) then you can't share cookies and thus you can't share a rails session.

There are many ways to deal with this, a simple one is known as [CAS](http://jasig.github.io/cas/development/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html) (Central Authentication Service) protocol. The basic flow with this is

1. User goes to hello.com and tries to access some protected resource (e.g. /home
2. User is redirected to `sso.example.com/service?=http://hello.com/home`
3. The user's identity is verified here as usual: the user either logs in, is recognised from a cookie etc.
4. The sso service generates a ticket (an arbitary token) and redirects the user to `http://hello.com/home?ticket=ABC123
5. The application at hello.com makes a (server side) request back to the SSO server, passing the ticket
6. The SSO server responds indicating whether the ticket is valid. If the ticket is valid it will also include some information about the user (e.g. email)
7. `hello.com` sets a session cookie so that subsequent requests can skip steps 2-6

There are ruby implementations of cas (e.g. [rubycas](http://rubycas.github.io) which has both a cas client and server) and devise [strategies](https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable)  that use CAS. There are of course other ways you can do this, for example using oath, but CAS is somewhat simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Rails maintain cookie which gets passed on to the server during every HTTP request. Please check the request headers under your network logs

You will see something like this

```
Cookie: some-junk-looking-session-data
```

So sharing session between two entirely different rails application is a security issue and rails don't allow this kind of behaviour.

However, there is an exception. A session can be shared if just the TLD changes. Eg: `hello.com` & `hello.org`.

```
YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
  key: '_app_session',
  domain: :all
```

References:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1091a6e9b700bd713c8a6818761a27aa72b1fe93

Comment: I have a application and there are two domain for this application. so when user logged in one domain then it should also logged in with second domain when both application open in same browser

Comment: I didn't give -1 someone else give it

Comment: As i said, It would only work if your domain are example.com and example.org