# Share session between a Rails 4 and a Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We have a setup in a way that currently some pages are being served by a Rails 4 app and a Rails 5 app. All the authentication logic resides in the Rails 4 app and we are using Devise for authentication. The `session_store.rb` on the Rails 4 app looks like this `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_store'`. I want to have the `current_user` accessible in the Rails 5 app as well. Note: Both the apps are under the same domain. Also how should I go about setting devise on my Rails 5 app so that current_user is accessible.

Comment: ok and both aps are sharing the same db with users in it ?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314817/share-session-between-two-rails4-applications?answertab=oldest#tab-top ?

Comment: yes. both are sharing the db

Answer (score -1):

First allow cookie to apply for all of your subdomains:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_store', domain: :all
```

When the browser accesses a website, the website tells the browser to set a cookie. When this happens, it specifies the cookie name, value, domain, and path.

**:domain => :all** makes a dot in front of the cookie domain (which is whatever host your browser has browsed to), so the cookie applies to all subdomains.

Another good thread about this topic can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4065929/1625253

Comment: why do i need to add `domain: :all`?

Comment: @AdamYoung Follow the link in my answer. I think you will find there what you need. Sorry, I have to go now. Tell me if it worked or come back to you later this week.

Comment: how should I go about setting devise on my Rails 5 app so that current_user is accessible?