# Sharing web sessions between Rails 5.2 app and Golang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, go, jwt

We have a Rails app which is the main site, but we created a separate app in Golang that handles a lot of other real-time functionalities like Video and Audio Calls, Messaging and Whiteboard sections.

The problem we have now is we don't know how to share web sessions between the 2 apps. When you switch in between the Rails app to Golang. Just like going from Gmail to Google Drive to YouTube, the session remains the same even though these apps run in different subdomains and sometimes different languages.

I was able to add the session from Rails + Devise/Warden into the browser cookie but the cookie is encrypted.  How do I decrypt or use this cookie to authenticate the user in Go?

Could you guys please share with me how you would approach solving this problem in your own app?

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314879/5012862) I was able to get the session cookie to appear both in the main site in React + Rails and the subdomain in React + Golang, but the cookie is encrypted, how do we decrypt/get the values in there? for example the user_id?

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using JWT, the problem I encountered with that is, I added the token in Browser Sessions and then Rails encrypted the token, so now I have to decrypt it on the Go side to be able to know the value.

Comment: I'm actually not asking for recommendations per se, it's a real I have and been trying to solve for about 1 week, I would appreciate if anyone can help with a solution.

Comment: I don't think you really want to share the cookie, you'd want to create a JWT and share that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share the session between two backends (regardless of the backends) using `redis` datastore as central shared memory.

So, whenever you create a new session in `Rails` or `Go` app:

- Create a session-id(UUID for ex.) `a59eb448-d268-413e-a837-b5aefc65a4b2`
- You will store your session details in `redis` with that unique session id (`a59eb448-d268-413e-a837-b5aefc65a4b2`).
- You store your session id in a cookie shared between the two platforms domains. So if it was `rails.mydomain.com` and `go.mydomain.com` then you need to make the cookie accessible from both subdomains `*.mydomain.com`.
- When a user with this cookie access any of your platform. You can read the session-id from his cookies and use it to query redis and get session info (user_id, etc.).

This way you can have shared session across different subdomains in the client side using cookies and shared across different backends in the server side using redis.

Answer (score 2):

You should give a try to [rails5session library](https://godoc.org/github.com/openware/rails5session-go):

From the [Readme](https://github.com/openware/rails5session-go/blob/master/README.md):

Create Encryption instance with your rails session secret key base (specified
in config/secrets.yml)

```golang
encryption := rails5session.NewEncryption(
    secretKeyBase,
    cookieSalt,
    signedCookieSalt,
)
```

- You can obtain your cookieSalt by running following ruby code:

  ```rb
  Rails.application.encryption.action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt
  ```
- You can obtain your signedCookieSalt by running following ruby code:

  ```rb
  Rails.application.encryption.action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt
  ```

Then verify and decrypt user's cookie, it will return decrypted slice of bytes
and error if any.

```golang
data, err := rails5session.VerifyAndDecryptCookieSession(encryption, cookie)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how do we get to call - rails5session.VerifyAndDecryptCookieSession in golang? with which algorithm do we verify and decrypt in golang?

Comment: You can find the answer in the code: https://github.com/openware/rails5session-go/blob/master/decrypt.go Should be easy to follow.

Comment: Thank you very much.